# CFL, pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I have difficulty with proving that the language 
$ L = \{ a^p b^q | p \ge 1 , q \ge 1 , p \ge q^2  \vee q \ge p^2\}$

$ w = uvxyz $

I've chosen word $ w = a^{N^2} b^N $ where $ N $ is a constant from pumping lemma and I proved cases where a $ v,y $ is entirely in $ a $ and $ v,y $ is entirely in $ b $ , but how to prove case where $ v \in a $ and $ y \in b $ ?
I think that the word $ w = a^{N^2} b^N $ isn't good, but I have no idea which one will be better.

Edit after comments

After comments, my solution is :

$ w = a^{n^2} b^N $  and $ w = uvxyz $ , so $ v = a^p $ and $ y = b^q $
where $ 1 \leq p + q \leq N $
After pumping i-times I get
$ w_i = a^{n^2 + ip} b^{N+iq} $

so to prove that this word isn't in language I should choose i such as regardless of N,p,q it won't be true
$ N^2 + ip \ge (N+iq)^2 $

$ N^2 + ip \ge N^2 + 2Niq + i^2q^2 $

$ ip \ge 2Niq + i^2q^2 $

for i = 1

$ p \ge 2Nq + q^2 $ which isn't true because $ 1 \leq p + q \leq N $

Is this correct ?

Comment: The choice of word is fine. All you need to do is the following: show that you can pick a $k$ such that $N^2 + ki < (N + kj)^2$ regardless of the choice of $N, i, j$. Remember: $|vy| < N$ and $|v|, |y| \neq 0$. Assume the worst-case choice of $v$ and $y$ for this case: $|v| = N - 1$ and $|y| = 1$. You should find that the choice $k = N$ works. Please give this a try and, if it works, post an answer.

Comment: @Patrick87 I updated my question, because I can't post answer due to the fact that I am new user and I have to wait 8 hours.

Comment: Hint: In LaTeX, type `\{ ... \}` for sets.

Comment: ... looks OK to me :) Looks like the choice $k = 1$, as in your version, works just fine. There's no way to grow $\#_a$ fast enough when you add any $b$, since the number of $a$ you can add is limited by the pumping lemma.

Comment: Could someone tell me why I got minus for this question ?

Comment: @user19369 Downvotes usually indicate that members don't like your question: that it shows no research effort or is not useful. Since you answer your own question, I assume it's because people don't find the question useful... maybe because they find it uninteresting? I wouldn't worry about downvotes - I've gotten plenty over the years. You'll get upvotes, too - just keep asking/answering questions. Thanks for participating!

Comment: (Plus, there might be quite similar questions to this one already on the site. Be sure to look around before asking a new question, just in case it has already been answered.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is taken from the question (the user was unable to post as an answer at the time).

After comments, my solution is :

$ w = a^{n^2} b^N $  and $ w = uvxyz $ , so $ v = a^p $ and $ y = b^q $
where $ 1 \leq p + q \leq N $
After pumping i-times I get
$ w_i = a^{n^2 + ip} b^{N+iq} $

so to prove that this word isn't in language I should choose i such as regardless of N,p,q it won't be true
$ N^2 + ip \ge (N+iq)^2 $

$ N^2 + ip \ge N^2 + 2Niq + i^2q^2 $

$ ip \ge 2Niq + i^2q^2 $

for i = 1

$ p \ge 2Nq + q^2 $ which isn't true because $ 1 \leq p + q \leq N $

Is this correct ?